# Calendar: prevent users to move events in the calendar

Tags: workflow, calendar

I have a calendar where users can apply for events, but with OOB permissions, they are also able to **pick and move events** - and this is unacceptable.
I cannot revoke edit permissions, otherwise they won't be able to book...
So far the only solution is using a workflow to reset the event date if it is changed, but I'd like to find a client solution (using JS/Jquery).
Some ideas? Thanks
Marco